# How to add month in Sheets cell that corresponds with formula in below adjacent cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates

I am making a cash flow projection worksheet in Google Sheets. I am using this formula to give me sequential weeks (greatly relieving the tedious entry)
`=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN("-",TEXT({"5/1","5/8"}+(COLUMN(A1)-1)*7,"M/DD")))`

In the cell directly above this formula, Id like the referenced month name to appear. So, above the above formula, MAY would appear.

Does anyone have the formula to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what this part is for:

> (COLUMN (A1) -1) * 7

because I believe that instead of A1 you have to insert a range, however try with this formula which has the same reference

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT("5/1"+(COLUMN(A1)-1)*7,"MMM"))
```

or an unique formula like this:

```
={TEXT("5/1"+(COLUMN(A1)-1)*7,"MMM");arrayformula(JOIN("-",TEXT({"5/1","5/8"}+(COLUMN(A1)-1)*7,"M/DD")))}
```

Comment: Hello Daniele, both of your suggestions work well for me, the second 'unique formula' being more convenient. I am perfectly satisfied and I have a question. On those weeks where the date range spans two months, 11/27-12/03 for example, this formula displays the previous month Nov vs Dec. What in the formula might be edited to pick up the end date to trigger the next month's name change more accurately?

Comment: simply change the "5/1" part of the formula for the monthName to "5/8"